# Is it possible to force the print dialogue box to ALWAYS show? (Windows XP)

Tags: printing

I am not sure if this is the best place to post this question, but I'm thinking the problem can be solved programmatically.

We use a program (web-based in IE) at work that in some instances of printing will essentially perform a "quick print" and will forgo showing the printer dialogue box for "convenience". Problem is that if we are printing invoices we want to use invoice paper, and our options are to:

1. Before printing swap out the paper for invoice paper
2. Change default printer settings (globally, settings can not be set per application as it is a web-based system) to print to manual tray then place paper in that tray then click print; change printer settings back to default afterwards
3. Post the invoice then go back and print the invoice using a separate function which allows the print dialogue box to show (more inconvenient than it sounds as the automatically assigned invoice # needs to be looked up before you can go to this step)

**Ideally I'd like to force my printer dialogue box to ALWAYS show with any print job, as this would also be useful in those times where I accidentally click "Quick Print" from Word before setting up my print job.**

Another option would be to create two shortcuts (batch files?) that would switch between the two defaults for our printers. Any ideas?